# Vertically and Horizontally center a div with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically and horizontally center a `div` inside another `div` that has the `overflow: hidden` I have successfully been able to horizontally center it, but not vertically.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Alot of content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -50%;
    right: -50%;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LSKRy/647/)

**Why is my `top: -50%` being ignored, but my `left: -50%` is working as expected?**

Comment: "I have successfully been able to horizontally center it"- i don't see anything horizontally centered in that fiddle... Btw, How do you center something that is being overflown, ie larger than it's parent..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy the very center of the `.content div` needs to be in the center of the `.outer div`. In the fiddle the `.content div` is horizontally in the center, but not vertically.

Comment: Why does this have `javascript` or `jquery` tags?

Comment: @BlakePlumb It isn't horizontally centered. It's `top` `left` corner is at the center of it's parent. That's not generally called "centered". If this is the case which corner you want to be vertically centered..? :/ ?? Maybe you need to rephrase the question...

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GvFv2/) by any chance?

Comment: You must be looking at the `.inner div` not the `.content div`

Comment: @moonwave99 That is exactly what I am looking for, but it needs to be dynamic. I don't know the exact width and height of my `.content div` in my real world case.

Comment: Then you need to do it via Javascript - play with `$.width()` / `$.height()` methods of jQuery ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to avoid using `translate3d` to solve this for older IE support, but in the end couldn't figure out why my `top: -50%` didn't work. :(

Here is the **CSS** I ended up with.

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LSKRy/651/)

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LSKRy/648/)**

Actually fiddle is not clear.

I don't know about horizontal center. So I added it. But if you don't want it skip it.

For vertically center, you may try this:

```
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center; //horizontal center
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell; //<-vertical center
    text-align: center; //<-vertical center
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always center any element using following code without negative margin hack.
The content will automatically align center from top, bottom, left, right

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: here is ur fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33T6U/1/ .. try changing the height or width of content

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/), you can use a class like this **as long as you have a declared height**:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

If you add that class to your outer div everything should work.